# How do I cancel an Etherscan transaction?

Tags: transactions, wallets, etherscan, hash

I did a transfer with Eth, the transaction shows completed, but I didn't received the coin in my wallet. How do I revert the transaction with its hash value?
Thank you.

Comment: Did you transfer that transaction wallet-to-wallet or contract-to-wallet?

Comment: You can rever a completed tx, show us the tx hash so we probably can help u unterstand what happened

Comment: *can't reverse..

Comment: Yes, it was a contract to wallet.

Comment: Here is the hash:

Comment: 0x9d3d0517e7907df96e3853fda6b70f620f358cf8a2ac3dffd82d3389666e0c30

Comment: @Scarfce 1)Do you mean your wallet doesn't add the transaction to the receipt transactions list? I mean did the wallet take a record for this transaction? Or just the wallet's balances didn't be updated? 2) How much did you transfer? 3) What is your wallet?

Comment: 1)My wallet didn't have the transaction receipt.

Comment: Apparently, the contract coins was only using the eth platform, but they send different crypto.